# Boto3 - Copy Object to a newly generated S3 location and return name in http body

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform

I have a lambda that runs via a http trigger in API Gateway.

My goal is to:

1. Copy files from `input-bucket` (where the user uploads his/her files)
2. Create a UUID as a new location/folder in a separate bucket (`output-bucket`)
3. Paste those objects in that new location
4. Delete all objects from `input-bucket` and return a 200 http status with the new location name in the body

However, I keep getting this:

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied
```

This is my lambda:

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger(__name__).setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

session = boto3.Session()
client = session.client('s3')

s3 = session.resource('s3')
src_bucket = s3.Bucket('input-bucket')

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    LOGGER.info('Reading files in {}'.format(src_bucket))

    location = str(uuid.uuid4()) 
    client.put_object(Bucket='output-bucket', Body='',Key = (location + "/"))

    LOGGER.info('Generated folder location ' + "/"+ location + "/ in output-bucket")

    for obj in src_bucket.objects.all():
        copy_source = {
                'Bucket': 'input-bucket',
                'Key': obj.key
            }
        client.copy_object(Bucket='output-bucket',
            Key=location + '/' + obj.key,CopySource = copy_source) ### ERROR OCCURS HERE
        LOGGER.info('Copied: {} from {} to {} folder in {}'.format(obj.key,'input-bucket',location,'output-bucket'))


    src_bucket.objects.all().delete()
    LOGGER.info('Deleted all objects from {}'.format(src_bucket))    
    return  { "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            'folder_name': location
        })
    }
```

As far as I know, I have enabled everything correctly for the s3 bucket policies (this is only for `output-bucket`, I have identical policies for `input-bucket`:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "file_output" {
  bucket = "output-bucket"
  acl    = "private"
  policy = <<EOF
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"ModifySrcBucket",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{
            "AWS":[
               "<XXXXXX>"
            ]
         },
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectTagging",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectTagging",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
         ],
         "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::output-bucket/*","arn:aws:s3:::output-bucket/*/*"]
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{
            "AWS":"<XXXXXXX>"
         },
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListBucket"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::output-bucket"
      }
   ]
}
    EOF
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "disable_acl_output" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.file_output.id

  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are both S3 Buckets in the same AWS Account as the Lambda function? If so, you **should not be using Bucket Policies**. Instead, **create an IAM Role** and assign the necessary permissions to the IAM Role, then assign the IAM Role to the AWS Lambda function. It will need `GetObject` and `DeleteObject` on the source bucket, and `PutObject` on the destination bucket.

Comment: Yes they are all in the same account. I will bear this in mind. Does this affect anything if I want to expose the bucket to an IAM user from another account?

Comment: Can I ask... _Why_ are you creating the empty object? It is not required to create folders in S3. You can simply copy files to a destination and the folders in the path will magically 'appear' (because they don't actually exist).

Comment: Oh I see, I hadn't realised that. Let me try doing that on the next iteration @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your source and destination S3 buckets are in the same account as the AWS Lambda function:

- Do **not** create a Bucket Policy
- Instead, **create an IAM Role** and assign it to the Lambda function
- Add these permissions to the IAM Role:

```json
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
         ],
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::input-bucket/*"
      },
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": "s3:ListBucket"
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::input-bucket"
      },
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": "s3:PutObject"
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::output-bucket/*"
      },
   ]
}
```

If the buckets were in *different* AWS Accounts, then you would need to put a Bucket Policy on the bucket in the 'other' account to grant permission for this IAM Role to be able to access it. (There are plenty of Answers on StackOverflow demonstrating how to do this.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe setting the permissions on the S3 bucket policy might not be enough. Your Lambda Execution role should have permissions to invoke some operations as well, as explained in the [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-copy-between-buckets/):

- **on the source bucket**: s3:ListBucket and s3:GetObject
- **on the destination bucket**: s3:ListBucket and s3:PutObject

There might be more permissions required based on your exact use case (server-side encryption with KMS, versioned objects, etc.).